# Como formatar input com float e range no Python 2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, range

Preciso fazer uma calculadora de média (notas de alunos) onde as entradas tenham uma casa decimal e estejam no intervalo [0, 10]. As saídas precisam apresentar cinco casas decimais e até agora, com o que consegui descrever, o código está:

```
a = float("%.1f" % input())  
b = float("%.1f" % input()) 
MEDIA = (a + b) / 2  
print 'MEDIA =', "%.5f" % MEDIA  
exit()
```

Como devo inserir o range nesse código pra limitar as entradas ao intervalo [0,10] com números de uma casa decimal?

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar a construção "while" para continuar perguntando enquanto a entrada não estiver boa, e a cosntrução "if" com condições para verificar isso. Outra boa prática, para evitar duplicação de código é usar uma função  -

Pode ser algo assim:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys

if sys.version[0] == '2':
    input = raw_input

def obtem_nota(nome):
   ok = False
   while not ok:
       texto = input("Por favor, digite a nota {}: ".format(nome))
       # tentamos converter a nota entrada como texto para um valor.
       # se ocorrer um erro, não foi um número válido:
       try:
           nota = float(texto)
       except ValueError:
           print("Entrada de nota incorreta. Digite novamente.", file=sys.stderr)
           continue
       # Verificar se há apenas um dígito apos o ponto,
       # E se não há caracteres além de digitos e .
       # e se o valor está entre 0 e 10:
       if (len(texto.split(".")[-1]) <= 1 and
           texto.replace(".", "").isdigit() and
           0 <= nota <= 10
          )
          ok = True
       else:
           print("Entrada de nota incorreta. Digite novamente.", file=sys.stderr)
   return nota

a = obtem_nota("a")
b = obtem_nota("b")
media = (a + b) / 2  
print ('MEDIA =', "%.5f" % media)
```

O jeito que você estava tentando fazer: 
`a = float("%.1f" % input())` deve dar erro, por que a formatação de string com código `"%f"` espera que o parâmetro seja um número - só que o input retorna uma string, e é só depois da chamada ao `float` que temos um número.   Ah, não dá erro por que você está usando Python 2 - que faz a conversão do valor no input automaticamente.

Uma outa coisa a se prestar tenção é que: enquanto estamos tratando com texto, faz sentido em falar "uma posição depois do ponto decimal" - ao converter o valor para float, ele passa a usar uma representação interna do computador que pode ocupar até várias casas depois da vírgula. Mas se limitarmos o valor enquanto ele ainda é texto, e formatarmos o texto de novo no momento da impressão com o número de casas desejadas, isso não é um problema.

E outro conselho que fica é: já que você está aprendendo a linguagem agora, aprenda Python 3 (a versão 3.6 de preferencia) - são algumas poucas diferenças, mas que tornam a linguagem muito mais consistente (por exemplo, o input sempre retorna texto, sem tentar adivinhar o que o usuário possa ter digitado) . No código acima eu coloquei algumas linhas preliminares de forma que o programa é escrito como em Python 3, mas vai funcionar também em Python 2.